# Activity did not call finish? (API 23)

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-lifecycle, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am getting the following error and i have no clue as to why its happening.

**Error:**

```
08-23 17:07:46.533  22454-22454/com.a.b.c E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.a.b.c, PID: 22454
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.a.b.c/com.a.b.c.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity {com.a.b.c/com.a.b.c.MainActivity} did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity {com.a.b.c/com.a.b.c.MainActivity} did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6324)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Started");
}
```

I am trying to run the code on an AVD running android 6.0 (API 23), works on API 22.

Comment: please, show me your onresume and onfinish method

Comment: I haven't overridden the onResume/onFinish methods. I have only used onCreate as shown above.

Comment: removing (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay")  from the android manifest has made it work, however i need this in my application so i need a workaround.

Comment: Link fixed. See accepted answer.

Comment: Is there any good alternative for android:theme="@and‌​roid:style/Theme.NoDi‌​splay" ?

Comment: @iYonatan [This](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html) might help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bug in Android M developer preview. [More details](https://web.archive.org/web/20151116170752/https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2353)

Comment: 1. broken link
2. this seems to be an intended change in behavior starting with api 23, not a bug, below answers can help, and this post to summarize it: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html

Comment: Link fixed. This is a bug recognized by Google developers.

Comment: This error still happens in Android 9.0, so I think it's safe to say that it's here to stay.

Answer (score 26):

I'm having the same problem, the same crash with the

> did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing

error message. So I created the v23\styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
...
</style>
```

while the normal styles.xml has

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoDisplay">
...
</style>
```

It works fine, no longer crashes. However, I don't know how good is this solution, to use Theme.Translucent in API 23, especially as it is [defined](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Translucent) as

> Theme for translucent activities (on API level 10 and lower).

I really hope they fix this bug.

Comment: I recommend `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`. Otherwise, you'll get an old-style title bar floating on the screen. Otherwise, this technique worked for me -- many thanks!

Comment: It looks like that is not a bug. Documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowNoDisplay says that "activity must immediately quit without waiting for user interaction". So as exception message suggests Activity needs to be finished before `onResume()` completes.

Answer (score 23):

I found a workaround. Call `setVisible(true)` in `onStart()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This does not work, at least as of Android 6.0 final. I still get the same exception as cited in the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare, sounds like they fixed it in the final version. The fix was working in the official emulator before the official 6 release. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: My apologies. I think I tried `setVisible(false)`. `setVisible(true)` avoids the crash, but you wind up showing a useless activity UI (black background, old-style gray title bar). `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` is closer to the visual results of `Theme.NoDisplay` (i.e., invisible).

Answer (score 6):

My invisible Activity shows a confirmation dialog. This did **lose the material design look** when I used `android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`.

So, based on answers above and CommonWare's blog and the Android themes definitions I use this style, which extends a normal AppCompat.Light theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoDisplay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: As my edit got rejected for some reason, answer is missing
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`
line to hide the statusbar when Activity is closed.

Comment: @Ako I added the line though it needs a separate `styles.xml` for api 21+

Comment: This answer already needs a app specific styles.xml included in the project.

Answer (score 6):

I have found the actual intended fix for this. The `Theme.NoDisplay` is only for

> activities that don't actually display a UI; that is, they finish themselves before being resumed.

Source: [Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_NoDisplay)

Therefore, if you assign this theme to an activity you *must* call `finish()` before exiting `onCreate()` (i.e. before the system calls `onResume`) This is why the error says "did not call finish() prior to onResume()".

So the actual usecase for this theme is bootstrap activities and the like, for example like this when you have to determine whether you show the login or main view depending on whether the user is already authenticated:

```java
public class BootstrapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!userLoggedIn) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

where android 23> 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAcUGwCkrcs

Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
Activity extends from Activity. Not AppCompatActivity.
```

and for version >= 23

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){     
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to setting a theme on an `Activity` that the user cannot see. I guess the reason Android does this is so you can't just run an invisible `Activity` indefinitely.

Calling `finish()` in your activity before `onResume()` gets called (like the error message says) will stop this from happening.

My use case was launching an invisible `Activity` to handle deep links and direct it to the correct part of my app.

Answer (score -4):

Try changing `targetSdkVersion` to 22 in build.gradle. `Theme.NoDisplay` shows error in api level 23.

Comment: changing target sdk version is not a soltution. Google has changed its policy to upgrade the target sdk to latest before updating or creating new app on playstore