# FacebookActivity did not call finish() on Api 23+

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using facebook sdk in my app. In order not to show the solo progress bar when facebook button is clicked, I am using:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
</activity>
```

However, I think for devices with api 23+ this causes a crash:

"com.facebook.FacebookActivity did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing"

Someone said here:[Activity did not call finish? (API 23)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169303/activity-did-not-call-finish-api-23) by writing:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

in the problematic activity, they solved the issue. But since I cannot edit FacebookActivity, is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Facebook have changed their [instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#login_share) for initially setting up your project. Just change the theme for the com.facebook.FacebookActivity to `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`.

Answer (score 0):

See javadoc of [windowNoDisplay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowNoDisplay) :

> (...)your activity must immediately quit without waiting for user interaction(...)

So exception is correct, your use case does not match `windowNoDisplay`.

Answer (score 0):

This is platform bug.

> If you have been using Theme.NoDisplay in one or more activities in
>   your app, and you have not tested them on Android 6.0 yet, I recommend
>   that you do so soon. An undocumented regression in Android 6.0 will
>   cause some of those activities to crash upon launch, if your
>   targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher.

See this blog post: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html