# Android 6.0+ Unable to resume activity , did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

**This my activity,no layout**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (getIntent().getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            NdefMessage[] msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
            runNFCTagData(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload());
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AlarmList.class));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.nfc_ndef_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Run it on android 6.0+ and it will be broken, you can see `Unable to resume activity` , did not call `finish()` prior to `onResume()`completing', but 6.0- is OK.I find a solution and it worked, but I don`t know why?

**This is my solution**
　 `@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setVisible(true);
    }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity did not call finish? (API 23)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169303/activity-did-not-call-finish-api-23)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a requirement when you use `Theme.NoActivity` as [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_NoDisplay):

> Default theme for activities that don't actually display a UI; that is, **they finish themselves before being resumed.**

Per [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html), this behavior is new to Android 6.0.

Comment: thanks, I know little about undocumented regression in Android 6.0

Comment: As per the Google+ post, the documentation never changed: it has always been something you've been required to do. It just didn't throw an Exception before.

Comment: What if I want to call startActivityForResult from such an activity? I cannot, and I am not finding a workaround for that

Comment: @David - just use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, which doesn't have this same restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You are using API > 21, so you can use the following style on your activity :

```
Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar
```

The trick with "setVisible(true)" is still not needed.